# Named Pipes error 40 in windows server 2003

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I have write one .Net application in C# I use these strings to connect

```
str = "Data Source=200.1xx.2yy.1zz ;Initial Catalog =minofom;uid =sa;pwd = abuelita";
```

and the same string for app.config:

```
<add name="MiniFinan.Properties.Settings.MiniFimConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=200.1xx.2yy.1zz ;Initial Catalog =minofom;uid=sa;pwd = abuelita" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

All the forms open fine, when I'm out of the local network, the app and the reports work perfect, but when I install the app in the server or any machine of the local network the app show me this error:

> “Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server”

The local server is a domain controller, I use this string for local area network:

```
str="Data Source=192.168.2.254 ;Initial Catalog =MinoFom;uid =sa;pwd = abuelita"
```

All the forms work, but when I call to any report not connect, I use the same string for the app.config. I have tested the same app in other Server 2003 (not Domain Controller) and the reports works, have any way of write the string for domain, any idea of how to fix this?

I have checked SQL Browser is online, the protocols : Shared Memory/ Named Pipes/TCPIP are installed and work. I think is something with the domain.

Comment: That looks like you are not passing in the `Port Number that Sql Server would be listening on` try putting in the `ipAddress:1433` or `IpAddress,1433` in your connection string [Trouble Shooting Error 40](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/22/483684.aspx)
[Part 2 trouble Shooting Error 40](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/29/486861.aspx)

Comment: I know this is old, but to anybody else reading this DO NOT CONNECT FROM AN APPLICATION AS sa! Ever. Quit your job if they try to force you to do it. Change careers or move away if it was the only job in town. Never, ever, ever, ever do this. I'm serious. Never...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved using two strings  one for the forms :

```
str = @"Data Source=TORRE ;Initial Catalog =minofom;uid =sa;pwd = abuelita";
```

and other in the app.config for the reports :

```
 connectionString="Data Source=MyDomain\TORRE;Initial Catalog=MinoFom;uid =sa;pwd = abuelita"
```

Its posible save more than one string in app.config , enjoy